# DC's compatible Bitmap

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

Q: I received a Bitmap's data buffer + BITMAPINFO description with 32 Bits per pixel.
The receiver's DC supports only 16 bits color.

When I create DIB object I pass the header + Bits, but that DIB will be displayed wrong...
How to make a compatible to receiver's DC Bitmap, which is based on 32's one?

Shouldn't be that clear though...

In other words: how to convert a DIB from 32 to 16, for example?

sorry, can't explain it better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`CreateDIBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183491(v=vs.85).aspx) function to convert a DIB to a DDB that is appropriate for the DC. It should apply the necessary conversions. If all you want to do is display the DIB, use [`SetDIBitsToDevice`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162974(v=vs.85).aspx) instead.